# How to keep an extra space from breaking this Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am accustomed to GNU make ignoring extra whitespace within variables, so I was surprised by the following.

```
## Makefile ##
PKGS = FOO BAR

FOO_DIR = foo
BAR_DIR = bar 
#            ^-------- Extra space at end of line

include $(foreach pkg, $(PKGS), $($(pkg)_DIR)/comp.mk)

default:
    @echo "Hello world!"
```

If there is a space after `BAR_DIR = bar`, make fails with this error:

```
'make: *** bar: Is a directory.  Stop.'
```

I think I understand what's happening here - there is a space in the include file path so make thinks I want to include a directory, hence the error. If the space is removed, and files `foo/comp.mk` and `bar/comp.mk` exist, make will run without error.

My question is, is there some way to protect against an extra space causing this failure?

Comment: make always preserves whitespace after a non-empty value in a variable assignment.  Another option, besides strip, is to use an editor which has a decent makefile mode, and will warn you about (or just delete for you) extraneous end-of-line whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip` to protect against that:

```
include $(foreach pkg, $(PKGS), $(strip $($(pkg)_DIR))/comp.mk)
```

For a similar reason, it's often wise to avoid spaces after commas when passing arguments to functions, including `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `strip` initially but I must of had it in the wrong place.